# typescript: make type that fits object literal values

Tags: typescript

given this object literal...

```
const views = {
  default: 'DEFAULT',
  user: {
    home: 'HOME',
    profile: 'PROFILE'
  }
}
```

I want to get a type like below without having to define it in multiple ways like defining a union type and then an object literal with all the types embedded

```
interface State {
  view: `DEFAULT' | 'HOME' | 'PROFILE'
}
```

Can I achieve this in Typescript?

**EDIT:**

I could defined a union type of strings

```
type View = 'HOME' | 'DEFAULT' | 'PROFILE'
```

and then declare the object literal (with the same values as the type above) but then I would have to define it in multiple ways and I would be repeating myself

Comment: Not clear about your question. What do you mean "in multiple ways" and "all the types embedded"

Comment: added the info to post

Answer (score 5):

If I got you correctly, this is what you want:

```
type View = 'HOME' | 'DEFAULT' | 'PROFILE'

interface Views {
  [key: string]: View | Views
}

const views: Views = {
  default: 'DEFAULT',
  user: {
    home: 'HOME',
    profile: 'PROFILE'
  },
  wrong: 'SOME_STRING', // error
}
```

UPD, after comments. Now, if you want to object literal be a reference of all possible strings you could naively do this:

```
const views = {
 default: 'DEFAULT',
    user: {
      home: 'HOME',
      profile: 'PROFILE'
    },
  }

// Make some peculiar types to extract all the strings
type Views = typeof views

type Strings<Obj> = Obj[keyof Obj]
type FlatStrings<T> = T extends object ? T[keyof T] : T

type View = FlatStrings<Strings<Views>>
```

But guess what type does `View` have? It's just `string`! Not `DEFAULT | HOME | PROFILE` as expected. Because typescript infers type `string` from object literal strings unless you rewrite the object literal like this:

```
const views = {
    default: 'DEFAULT' as const,
    user: {
      home: 'HOME' as const,
      profile: 'PROFILE' as const
    },
  }
```

Comment: but, then I have to define the strings in two places. I want to define it in one object literal and then somehow extract all the possible string values and make a union type out of that

Comment: @deltaskelta "in two places" - why? There is one place `type View` where you define strings, isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: @deltaskelta or do you want the object literal `views` to be the reference/storage of all the possible strings?

Comment: for example you can see 'DEFAULT' two times in your answer, that is the two places where it is defined once in the object literal and once in the type

Comment: @deltaskelta What you are trying to achieve is incorrect, and when I was the beginner in typescript I thought in the same way, but I was wrong as well. I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @deltaskelta took a while, but I guess I've managed to explain it.

Comment: @deltaskelta I am looking forward to receiving your feedback!

Comment: I disagree that there is no double work. This may be the correct way to do it in typescript, but it is still code duplication that requires work to duplicate and takes up space in a file and adds mental overhead

Comment: @deltaskelta When it comes to double work, I am the strongest proponent of DRY rule. However in this case I really don't feel that there is any double work. However, as I mentioned before, I used to. But today (thanks to typescript philosophy among other things) I know things should be separated by concern. Interfaces and data should be apart. For example, what would happen if your `views` object will have to change, but *not* the interface it also provides? Anyway, if I've managed to help you consider upvoting and selecting my answer.